# How to add a menu to MapActivity?

Tags: android, google-maps

I've got an app using MapActivity.onCreate() to initialize the map and show it on screen. Now I would like to add a menu to my app. From what I've found out I can't add a menu from MapActivity and need to use Activity (correct me if I'm wrong).

Now I have no idea how to "initialize" the map from my Activity-class.

And how would I have to fix the views, will I wrap my activity-layout around my Map-layout?

Comment: I didn't try this - but i'd expect MapActivity to be a subclass of Activity.
Did you try to override menu methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MapActivity` extends a regular Android `Activity`, so there's nothing irregular you should need to do to create a menu.

Just override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, [as shown in the developers' guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu).

Answer (score 0):

[MapActivity](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html) extends [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), so you should be able to add a menu.

Answer (score 0):

MapActivity is a subclass of Activity, and thus you do it the same way as in any normal Activity ([instructions here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)).  I've been able to successfully create menus the same way in MapActivity as in a normal Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it doesn't extend from `FragmentActivity` but from `AppCompatActivity`!

If that's the case, the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method will be called and you are able to overwrite it like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); //"menu_main" is the XML-File in res
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```